# Find the sum of the number of constructible polygons

Tags: geometry

> Let $R(n)$ equal $1$ if a regular $n$-sided polygon is constructible with a ruler and compass and $0$ if it is not. What is $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 3}^{100}R(n)$?

This question seems very hard to solve without just listing out all $n$ and seeing which $n$ have $\phi(n) = 2^m$. Is there any simple method to solve this question?

Answer (score 2):

1573035
There is a version of the Pascal Triangle which may be of use to you. It consists of the modulo-2 residues of the members of the Triangle. Observe:

$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc|l}
&&&&&&&1&&&&&&&&=1\\
&&&&&&1&&1&&&&&&&=3\\
&&&&&1&&0&&1&&&&&&=5\\
&&&&1&&1&&1&&1&&&&&=15\\
&&&1&&0&&0&&0&&1&&&&=17\\
&&1&&1&&0&&0&&1&&1&&&=51\\
&1&&0&&1&&0&&1&&0&&1&&=85\\
1&&1&&1&&1&&1&&1&&1&&1&=255
\end{array}$

Notice that
(1) each new row is one item longer than its predecessor and always begins and ends with 1;
(2.1) a 0/0 or 1/1 pair yields a 0 in the next row;
(2.2) a 0/1 or 1/0 pair yields a 1 in the next row.

Each of these rows may be considered as a digit-by-digit representation of a binary number. Excepting the apex, each of these binary numbers represents the number of sides of a constructible odd-number regular polygon in ascending order of size. The final valid number in the series is $2^{32}-1$, the product $3\times 5\times 17\times 257\times 65537$.

3,5,6,10,12,15,17,20,24,30,34,40,48,51,60,68,80,85,96.
So, your answer is 19.

====================
(written in QB64)
FUNCTION R~`(n~%%)
-->a~%% = n~%% 'make copy of argument

'eliminate powers of 2 from argument
-->WHILE((a~%% MOD 2) = 0)
----->a~%% = a~%% \ 2
-->WEND

'eliminate single instances of allowed odd factors from argument
-->IF((a~%% MOD 3) = 0) THEN a~%% = a~%% \ 3
-->IF((a~%% MOD 5) = 0) THEN a~%% = a~%% \ 5
-->IF((a~%% MOD 17) = 0) THEN a~%% = a~%% \ 17
-->IF((a~%% MOD 257) = 0) THEN a~%% = a~%% \ 257
-->IF((a~%% MOD 65537) = 0) THEN a~%% = a~%% \ 65537

-->R~` = (a~%% = 1) 'R = 1 if constructible, 0 if not
END FUNCTION

Comment: Brilliant! Nice one :-)

Comment: Is this the number of sides of a constructible polygon? Because if the regular polygon is constructible then it equals $1$.

Comment: No, these numbers represent the number of sides in regular polygons of odd numbers of sides that are constructible under Mr. Euclid's rules. There other constructible polygons derivable from these by multiplying these odd numbers by powers of 2.

Comment: The question was that if a polygon with $n$ number of sides is constructible with ruler and compass, then $R(n) = 1$ and if not $R(n) = 0$. Are you answering a different question?

Comment: @Puzzled417 \ Bear in mind that YOU are the one who wanted a count of the indices of the various constructible regular polygons from 3 to 100. Goodbye!